# Making the save and cancel buttons editable

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code makes a div tag editable and handles the <kbd>save</kbd> and <kbd>cancel</kbd> buttons. But there is a lot of duplication. How could I remove the duplication on this?

```
var originalTexts = {};
$("div.edit-panel").find("span").click(function() {
    var panel = $(this).closest('div.simple-panel');
    var text  = panel.find(".info");
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    panel.find(".edit-panel").addClass('editable');
    text.addClass("content-editable").prop('contenteditable', 'true');
    originalTexts[id] = text.text();
})

$("div.edit-panel").find(".cancel-editable").click(function() {
    var panel = $(this).closest('div.simple-panel');
    var text  = panel.find(".info");
    var id    = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    text.text(originalTexts[id]);
    panel.find(".edit-panel").removeClass('editable');
    text.removeClass("content-editable").prop('contenteditable', 'false');
})

$("div.edit-panel").find(".save-editable").click(function() {
    var panel = $(this).closest('div.simple-panel');
    var text  = panel.find(".info");
    var currentText = text.text();
    text.text(currentText);
    panel.find(".edit-panel").removeClass('editable');
    text.removeClass("content-editable").prop('contenteditable', 'false');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using just one declaration and an if block? You remove the top three lines by this for each function -

assuming buttons are `<button>`

```
var originalTexts = {};
$("div.edit-panel").find("button,span").click(function(){
    var panel = $(this).closest('div.simple-panel');
    var text  = panel.find(".info");
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    var currentText = text.text();

    if ($(this).is("span")){
        panel.find(".edit-panel").addClass('editable');
        text.addClass("content-editable").prop('contenteditable', 'true');
        originalTexts[id] = text.text();
    }else if ($(this).hasClass("cancel-editable")){
        text.text(originalTexts[id]);
        panel.find(".edit-panel").removeClass('editable');
        text.removeClass("content-editable").prop('contenteditable', 'false');
    }else if ($(this).hasClass("save-editable")){
        text.text(currentText);
        panel.find(".edit-panel").removeClass('editable');
        text.removeClass("content-editable").prop('contenteditable', 'false');
    }
});
```

You can reduce more codes if you can store the id and other information inside the `data` attributes of each `button`. But I don't know the html, so could not suggest on that.

Comment: Very nice approach. What I did is putting all the code inside $("div.edit-panel").each(function()... and saving that three lines of code too

Answer (score 1):

It is always possible to avoid duplicate code but we need to think deep inside of actual requirements. ActiveHigh did good job but we can improve readability and remove duplicate code:

```
var originalTexts = {};
$("div.edit-panel").find("button,span").click(function(){
  var $currentTarget = $(this);
  var $panel = $currentTarget.closest('div.simple-panel');
  var $textElement  = $panel.find(".info");
  var id = $currentTarget.parent().attr("id");
  var currentText = $textElement.text();
  var contenteditable = false;

  if ($currentTarget.is("span")){
    contenteditable = true;
    originalTexts[id] = $textElement.text();
  }else if ($currentTarget.hasClass("cancel-editable")){
    $textElement.text(originalTexts[id]);
  }else if ($currentTarget.hasClass("save-editable")){
    $textElement.text(currentText);
  }

  var handelClass = (contenteditable?'add':'remove') +'Class';
  $panel.find(".edit-panel")[handelClass]('editable');
  $textElement[handelClass]("content-editable").prop('contenteditable', contenteditable);
});
```

Kindly consider following points when You use jQuery lib in your JavaScript:

1 - Naming convention for jQuery elements:

```
var $currentTarget = ...;
var $panel = ...;
```

2 - Cache DOM element for further usage, it improve performance.

```
var $currentTarget = $(this);
```

Happy JavaScript coding :)